# Is there any reason to use file-loader when using url-loader with limit option?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

Using webpack-4

As far as I understood, the url-loader will have the same behavior than the file-loader if you set the limit option (it uses it under the hood), I noticed my image loading was broken when I used the conf below

```
{test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|png|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000'}

{test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|png|svg)$/, use: 'file-loader'}
```

**when I remove the `file-loader` it's working fine**, 
`url-loader` is catching everything **you need.
A few questions below:

1. In the conf above file-loader is breaking url-loader behavior (probably because I don't clearly specify the output folder) Am I understanding it well ?
2. what are the cases you really need `file-loader` ?
3. what are the **cases when it's good to do a combination of both** (if any) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. In the conf above file-loader is breaking url-loader behavior (probably because I don't clearly specify the output folder) Am I understanding it well ?

When defining both loaders you will have the behaviour of both, which is to encode all files in-place into base64 strings when their size is < 10000 bytes AND to copy all of them into your distribution directory.

You were right to remove the `file-loader` loader declaration if the behaviour you want is you want is to either encode as base64 when size < 10000 bytes OR copy to distribution folder when size > 10000 bytes.

Because `url-loader` has a `fallback` option, and it's default value is `file-loader`, the second `file-loader` declaration is unnecessary IF the files being targeted are the same for each loader.

> 2. what are the cases you really need file-loader ?

Whenever you want to copy a file to your dist directory and have reference to this file's location in the public path (where static assets will be served from; the `publicPath` webpack conf. property) within your bundled application. For example if you configured `file-loader` to copy images and name them as `[hash].[ext]` you can do:

```
const img = require('avatar.jpg')
console.log(img) // => /public/[hash].jpg
```

> 3. what are the cases when it's good to do a combination of both (if any) ?

Use both if you have files you always want to copy (`file-loader`) and files that you may want to encode into your bundle files (`url-loader`). Be careful not to target the same file types with both loaders, otherwise you may be copying files over that are also being encoded into your bundles with `url-loader`.

Comment: so to resume it, url-loader and file-loader shouldn't be use to target the same file type right ?

Comment: Finally, Now I understand the difference between url-loader and file-loader and how to use them. Didn't know that url-loader has a fallback by default to file-loader. :D